# Systematic construction of the ODE system of a circuit containing opamps

Tags: operational-amplifier, analysis

I want to compute the voltages and currents in a circuit containing R,L,C, opamps and voltage sources. I perfectly understand how to do this for circuits containing only R,L,C and voltage sources, using mesh or nodal analysis. But as soon as a circuit contains an opamp, I'm stuck.

In the literature I found, it is explained only by example (typically the inverting and non-inverting opamp), but no general "algorithm" is given.

Can somebody please explain to me how to construct the DE system for circuits of arbitrary size which contain opamps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming if you want to construct your ode systematically, you're actually thinking about doing this on a computer -- basically writing your own simulator.

Probably the key difference between the op-amp and R, C, L, or V elements is that those devices are all one-port devices while the op-amp is a two-port. The first port is the input pins, the second port is the output pin and the ground pin.

To set up the equations, you can treat the input as a very high resistance, in the gigaohm range (better yet, pick a real op-amp and use the value from its datasheet). It's probably not a good idea to make the input resistance infinite the way we do for hand calculation, because that could lead to an unsolvable set of equations if there's no other path to ground for one of the nodes in your circuit.

The second port is just like a voltage source, and you set it up in your equations the same way, but with the extra feature that its voltage depends on two other nodes in the circuit -- the input pins. Again, you probably won't want to assume infinite gain like in hand calculation, just use a high number, maybe 10^6, or use the open loop gain value from a real part.

Comment: That was the hint I needed. I wasn't aware that the input pins, and the output pin and ground each form a port.

Answer (score 0):

The usual *small signal* approximation used for an op amp operating with negative feedback and in its linear region is that both inputs are always at the same potential, and that the inputs draw no current, i.e. have infinite impedance.  But why are you trying to set up systems of differential equations involving op amps in the first place? Constructing and solving systems of differential equations for more than a few circuit elements is a nightmare.  If all you care about is the small signal behavior of the circuit involving the R,L,Cs and opamps, why not just analyze it directly in the Laplace domain, using the s domain impedances for resistances and capacitances \$\frac{1}{sC}, sL\$?

If you are interested in the large signal behavior of the circuit, then indeed the only way to analyze it is through a system of differential equations.  However, you will then have to use a *large signal* model of the op amp in question, and no general "algorithm" exists.

Comment: I'm interested in the small signal behavior. I agree that analyzing the system in the Laplace domain is easier, but there I too have to set up a set of equations. I'm interested in setting up these equations in a systematic way.

Comment: @max Sometimes in the Laplace domain it's possible to write down the transfer function of a circuit of the type you're considering basically from inspection.  If that's not possible, you can use nodal analysis with the small signal approximation of the op am given above, so long as the caveats on that model are obeyed.  In the latter case you end up with a system of algebraic equations, rather than a system of differential equations, because that's the purpose of the Laplace transform.

Comment: Is it also possible to use mesh analysis with the small signal approximation of the op amp?

Comment: When using mesh analysis, you first determine the nodes in the circuit (locations to which at least 3 components are connected), and the edges in the circuit (connections between nodes). Is this definition of nodes unchanged when op amps are present? Which are the possible edges in the circuit when op amps are present? As I can see, there are 3 possible paths through an op amp, can each of them be part of a mesh?